# Is it possible to stop laptop's battery from charging?

Tags: laptop, battery

I use Dell Inspiron N4030 laptop. In win7 I was installing Dell Battery software that it was showing battery status and providing a tool for stopping it from charging(when it's connected to AC power)
In Ubuntu it's not possible to do this work and I scare to hurt my battery due to the overcharge. 
Is there any way?

Comment: This comment has nothing to do with the question but may be useful nonetheless - suggest reviewing www.batteryuniversity.com to see how modern batteries are charged. A lot of the material on that site is way too technical for me to understand, but the "do's and don'ts" are quite useful.

Comment: @Alvar, I think the OP is asking about having the laptop autmatically stop charging the battery at a certain percentage. This is thought to increase the long-term durability of the battery.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can !
Download pre-compiled .deb from: https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-uk/sln311302/dell-command-configure?lang=en

Then just run:

```
sudo /opt/dell/dcc/cctk --primarybatterycfg=custom:60-80
```

It sets the maximal charge to 80%.

If you want to go back:

```
sudo /opt/dell/dcc/cctk --primarybatterycfg=Adaptive
```

Answer (score 0):

that dependes of the laptop and his design cause in my work repairing laptops some times even if the motherboard is death the battery still reach charge, because it works with a independent IC chip.